# Error using Chol decomposition on positive definite matrix

Tags: matrix, decomposition

I have the following two 2x2 matrices:

> A =   [0.0087    0.0368;
>        -0.0368    0.0087]
>
> B =     [1.5653    2.0499;
>             -2.0499    1.5653]

I have checked that the Hermitian part of each of the matrices are positive definite:

> eig(0.5*(A+A'))>0

so I don't know why using `chol(A)` returns an error saying that the matrix must be positive definite.

Am I missing something?